# Observable notify parent ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have a observableArray `fieldChoices` that contains observables like the following ones: `{ name: ko.observable('new choice') }`

I want to get the Observables to notify the ObservableArray which has to notify another computed.

I am binding them like this:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: $parent.fieldChoices">
     <div>
        <i class="icon-caret-right"></i>
        <input type="text" class="span8" data-bind="value: name(), test: name()" />
        <i class="icon-arrow-up" data-bind="click: $parentContext.$parent.shiftChoiceUp, visible: $index() !== 0"></i>
        <i class="icon-arrow-down" data-bind="click: $parentContext.$parent.shiftChoiceDown, visible: $index() !== ($parentContext.$parent.fieldChoices().length - 1)"></i>
        <i class="icon-remove" data-bind="click: $parentContext.$parent.removeChoice, visible: $parentContext.$parent.fieldChoices().length > 2"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the observables to notify the observable array when the `name` value changes. I tried to add a custom binding `test: name()` and notify from there. The problem is that the binding is not updated when the value is changed.

How can I get this working?

**EDIT :** Even though there are similar questions I am trying to solve this with a custom binding. I wasn't able to find any solutions for this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't make a ton of sense to me because by default what you are describing works (observables notify their subscribers when values change).  You can create an extender for your observables which notify your observableArray explicitly if you want, but you probably don't want to notify the observableArray that the observable changed (because then it won't notify anyone else, because *it's* value *hasn't* changed) you probably just want to do some common function -

Create an observable array  -

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray();
```

register an extender -

```
ko.extenders.trackChildChanges = function (target, value) {
    target.subscribe(function () {
        // Do some notification
    });
    return target;
};
```

And then create your observables and extend them -

```
function child(object) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id).extend({trackChildChanges: true});
    self.Name = ko.observable(name)extend({trackChildChanges: true});
}

var regArray = [{ id: 1, name: 'Bill'}, {id: 2, name: 'John'}];

$.each(regArray, function(index, item) {
    myArray.push(new child(item));
});
```

Comment: My main goal is to get the `computed` to re-evaluate when the value of the observable changed. I thought that there is a way to get the subscription when the value changes in a custom binding and from there to force the `computed` to reevaluate. But I will give it a go using extenders because I should solve it.

Comment: @razvan All you need to do is just create a write: function on the computed and write to it from that extender...

Answer (score 0):

Your fieldChoices (observable array) gets update when items are added and taken from the array, not when the item changes values. I suggest you subscribe to each item in the array.

```
var thingsToDoWhenAnItemsNamePropertyChanges = function(NewValue){
    alert('An items name property change to '+NewValue);
}
var arr = fieldChoices();
for(var i=0, cnt=arr.length;i<cnt;i++){
   var item = arr[i];
   var nm = item && item.name;
   if(typeof(nm.subscribe) === 'function')nm.subscribe(thingsToDoWhenAnItemsNamePropertyChanges);
}
```

Or if you already loop through the items while loading them into fieldChoices then you can subscribe to each objects name property then.