# Getting a child property of an observableArray item to trigger a change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

#### Problem

I have a `shoppingcart` viewmodel  with an `observableArray` of `cartitems` view models.

When I update the `subtotal` property of my `cartitems` view model, a computedObservable on my `shoppingcart` viewmodel needs to update but I don't know how to get it to trigger the update

#### Example

```
function shoppingcart() {
    var self = this;
    self.cartItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        _.each(self.cartItems(), function (item) {
            total += item.subTotal;
        }
    }

    //inital load of the data
    dataservice.loadCartItems(self.cartItems);
}



function cartItem() {
    var self = this;
    self.quantity = ko.observable(0);
    self.price = 0.00;

    self.subTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.price * self.quantity();
    }
}
```

Then in my view I have something similar to this

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: cartItems'>
    <!--other stuff here -->
    <input type='text' data-bind="value: quantity, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
</ul>

<span data-bind='value: grandTotal'></span>
```

Is this suppose to work and I've just messed up somewhere along the line, or do I need to add something else to get this to update?

Right now the grandTotal in the span will not be updated when the quantity in the textbox is changed.  I'm assuming it's because this child property doesn't actually count as the cartItems collection being changed.

What's a good way to trigger the update to the collection here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not returning anything from your `grandTotal` computed. Also, you were trying to add the `subTotal` function to the running `total` instead of its return value. You need to invoke with parenthesis in order to invoke the computed on `cartItem`.

```
function shoppingcart() {
    var self = this;
    self.cartItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        _.each(self.cartItems(), function (item) {
            total += item.subTotal(); // need parenthesis to invoke
        }
        return total; // return a value, otherwise function is void
    }

    //inital load of the data
    dataservice.loadCartItems(self.cartItems);
}

function cartItem() {
    var self = this;
    self.quantity = ko.observable(0);
    self.price = 0.00;

    self.subTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.price * self.quantity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, yeah those were actually typos as I just typed in the example off the top of my head, but that led me to find the error in my real code (very similar issue).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, the main problem is that you need trigger an observableArray mutation when one of its element changes. It can be done, but I don't know if it's a best practice. See this for an alternative implementation: [Observable notify parent ObservableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731105/observable-notify-parent-observablearray)

The example solution at this fiddle calls valueHasMutated manually: http://jsfiddle.net/F6D6U/6/

html:

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: cartItems'>
    <!--other stuff here -->
    <input type='text' data-bind="value: quantity, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
     * <span data-bind="text:price"></span>
    = <span data-bind="text:subTotal"></span>
    <br />
</ul>

<span data-bind='text: grandTotal'></span>
```

js:

```
function cartItem(q, p, a) {
    var self = this;
    self.quantity = ko.observable(q);
    self.price = p;
    self.parentArray = a;

    self.subTotal = ko.computed(function() {        
        var subtotal =  parseFloat(self.price,10) * parseFloat(self.quantity(),10);
        self.parentArray.valueHasMutated();
        return subtotal;
    },self);
}


function shoppingcart() {
    var self = this;
    self.cartItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.cartItems([
        new cartItem(10,100, self.cartItems),
        new cartItem(1,3, self.cartItems),
    ]);
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cartItems(), function (item) {
            total += item.subTotal();
        });
        return total;
    }, self);

    //inital load of the data
    //dataservice.loadCartItems(self.cartItems);
}

        ko.applyBindings(new shoppingcart())
```

Comment: Looks like I had just fumbled up my code and it does work out of the box if the sub items are observable.  But +1 for bringing up the valueHasMutated.  I won't need it here but it's nice to know of.  I see what you mean about not sure if best practice..doesn't seem right to keep a reference to the parent array in the subitem in this   example at least